# javascript to detect presence of div class and change innerHTML of a different div if true

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement

I maintain (but didn't develop) ASP site that has a comments form on its blog pages.
When a comment is added, the page shows a new div styled with the class "comments-wrap".  If there is no comments yet, that div won't appear at all.  It doesn't us an ID because there may end up being multiple comments on the page.

I want to add a new div to the page(s) that is empty (maybe using a &nbsp or the style display:none) unless the a script detects the presence of the "comments-wrap" class.

For example's sake, lets call the new div .  I'd like it to be present on the page all of the time (eg.   ), but the space changes to "Previous Comments" when the "comments-wrap" class is detected on the page.

So far I have:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
if ($(".comments-wrap")[0]) { 
document.getElementById("comments-previous").innerHTML="Previous Comments";
}
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery use `.length` to find the number of elements currently matched

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       if ($(".comments-wrap").length) { 
          $("#comments-previous").html('Previous Comments');
       }
   });
</script>
```

**Edit**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($(".comments-wrap").length) { 
        $("#comments-previous").html('Previous Comments');
    }
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>
 <div class="comments-wrap"></div>
 <div id="comments-previous"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I notice that the developers are calling <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> in the head... will that do?

Comment: Yes. You have to use jquery library file.

Comment: The test html is:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#comments-previous {
 font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
 font-size: 18px;
 color: #F90;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>

<h1>My Web Page</h1>

<div id="comments-previous">&nbsp;</div>

<script> 
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
       if ($(".comments-wrap").length) {  
          $("#comments-previous").html('Previous Comments'); 
       } 
   }); 
</script> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: Your Jquery library file url is broken. I have updated my anser try that. Better you can download the jquery file from http://jquery.com/download/ and use it directly from your site.

Comment: Legend!

You got it working.
I've added the code to the head of the blog items template, so all new blog pages generated will have the same code.

Thanks again